# Bionicle generation 3

Tags: technic, bionicle

Hey LEGO will you make another Bionicle reboot? If you are is it going to be a bit more like g1 but also bring back a few g2 characters and I hope it is either ccbs, you bring it back or technic like the original, and not system.

Comment: This is something that only Lego can answer. We are not the Lego set developers, and it is not possible for us to find leaked content of upcoming sets. If that's what you want then you practically have to be a spy to get your info.

Answer (score 1):

While only LEGO themselves can answer this question, there is a proposal for a [20 years of bionicle](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/9a9b428b-108e-43bd-8b9e-3fdc7e8ec54a) set on LEGO ideas that had achieved 10,000 votes and is currently under review. Depending on the outcome of the review process, it may become an officail LEGO set in a few month.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like a set showcasing Bionicle robots that have already existed before in other sets.

Comment: Yes, of course. In LEGO ideas you can only use existing elements.